# PHP script with MySQL statement with single quote

Tags: php, mysql, function, user-defined-functions

I'm learning PHP,MySQL and came across this function today

```
function get_director($director_id) {
global $db;
$query = 'SELECT 
        people_fullname 
   FROM
       people
   WHERE
       people_id = ' . $director_id;
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
extract($row);

return $people_fullname;
}
```

I understand what functions are and I've created a few while learning PHP.But this one is a bit more complicated.I can't understand the

```
WHERE people_id = ' . $director_id
```

I guess the single quote ends the MySQL statement? And then it is concatenated with the argument?

Comment: To avoid Sql Injection you should `addSlashes($director_id)`

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string(). Not addSlashes.

Comment: @KyleBoddy, that's right, I haven't used a non-PDO in a while.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess the single quote ends the MySQL statement?And then it is concatenated with the argument? Please help me out.

That is correct.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

```
<?php
$a = "Hello ";
$b = $a . "World!"; // now $b contains "Hello World!"

$a = "Hello ";
$a .= "World!";     // now $a contains "Hello World!"
?>
```

EDIT: The meaning of the WHERE clause is best explained by the psuedo explanation of what the entire statement does.

SELECT everyone's full name WHERE their people_id is EQUAL TO some value passed into the function.

However, you are way over your head if you are evaluating these things and don't understand the basic SQL. I recommend you read the entire Tiztag PHP/MySQL tutorial.

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/

Comment: Please tell me what's the meaning of that WHERE clause in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, the single quotes end the sql string and concatenate with the supplied argument. Same case if you want to print the value out.

```
echo 'This is the director ID :'.$director_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call this operator an "SQL statement". And wouldn't say it is "closed" either.
For PHP it's just a string with no particular meaning.
And the quote ends this string literal, not SQL statement.

Strictly speaking here is just a concatenation, a string literal with a variable.

Having a whole complete SQL statement as a result.

Comment: Would you please tell me what that $query variable actually does?To be specific,what does the 
    
 WHERE people_id = ' . $director_id;

part of the code do?What's the condition to pull data from people_fullname

Comment: better ask this as a separate question. Just post this query without PHP, only the query itself without surrounding quotes(make it with people_id = 1 to make it consistent)

Comment: I just want to know the meaning of that WHERE clause.Should I post a separate thread for that?

Comment: yes, exactly. this question has nothing to do with PHP and functions. If you have a question about SQL - ask it separately

Answer (score 1):

The .(dot) is used for concatenation in php.
If you pass 32 to $director_id then the final query will be
select people_name from people where people_id = 32
If you pass 43 to $director_id then the final query will be 
select people_name from people where people_id = 43

Means the .(dot) is used for appending the value of $director_id to the string in single quotes.

The final query will be passed to mysql. Using .(dot) is just a method in php to generate the final query that we want to execute in mysql.